# CMUS doesn't run correctly in TMUX session

Tags: tmux, cmus

[image: cmus_in_tmux]

As you can see in the screenshot, `cmus` doesn't display correctly inside `tmux`.

Normally, starting `cmus` directly works fine. But I ask because I want to use the [detachable hack](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/wiki/detachable-cmus).

I can't figure out what is screwing it up. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `$TERM` variable to `xterm-256color` worked for me.

If you run POSIX compliant shell, run `export TERM=xterm-256color` or `set TERM xterm-256color` if you use the fish shell.